# World to Cube projection Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

**That's the setting:**

[image]

I have 2 cameras in the game scene. The game must be played in a room with screens on frontal wall and on the floor. To be able to test it I just recreated the 2 screens in Unity. The goal is to make the game immersive, creating the correct illusion as the image on the left.
What I've tried so far (and it kinda worked as you can see from the screenshot) is:

Camera0: goes directly in the frontal display.

Camera1: I created a post processing effect that deforms the output texture to create the correct perspective illusion.

**The problem:**

The fact that I'm basically working over a texture creates some blurry effect on the borders, because the pixel density is not the same in start and deformed image.

I think the best approach would be to make the deforming transformation happen on the projection matrix of Camera1 instead. But I just failed. Have you any idea on how to approach this problem correctly?

Comment: what deform is necessary? set the fov of the floor camera so that it shows only as much as will fit on the screen. Then have the cameras at the same position and have the floor camera rotated on the +x axis by half of the sum the fov of both cameras.

Comment: That's awesome. It works just great. I didn't relized that this was posdible with only the correct placement of the cameras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let your perspective cameras do the work for you.

Set the fov of the floor camera so that it shows only as much as will fit on the screen.

Then, have the cameras at the same position.

Finally, have the floor camera rotated on the +x axis by half of the sum the fov of both cameras. For example, if the wall camera is fov 80º and the floor fov is 40º, set the floor camera to be rotated by 60º along the x axis.

This will guarantee that the view of the cameras do not overlap, and they will have the correct projection along their surfaces to create the desired illusion.

Comment: It turn out that must hold an additional condition: the fov of both camera has to be the same. Maybe I can ask you another question. Given all the info about camera and geometry (positions, sizes) of the screens, how can I say at what position the player should be standing up in order to have the correct perspective?

Comment: Had to think a little more about it - I think there's a way using trig to determine that. But, since the player's height and the sizes of the screens are rather fixed, maybe it would be better to ask if you have the position of the player's head and the sizes of the screens, how to set up the cameras? First it would matter how large a game unit should be compared to the real life player. Typically 1 game unit is treated as a meter but is that what you would like?

Comment: My answer assumes the player's head is in the dead center of the box shaped by the 2 planes but that need not be the case so a more variable solution might be desired. I'll come back to this and try to put it in the answer. When/If I do I'll @ you so you get a notification and can review it

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I think the main issue is that the default projection is centered on the camera. If I translate up the frustum of the top camera maybe I can control the player height. What you think?

Comment: @FedericoAlterio I think what you need to look into is setting the frustum to be oblique - Too busy to look into the details at the moment https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ObliqueFrustum.html

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was thinking too